# jQuery show/hide multiple values from dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to hide some checkboxes based on a value from a select box. I can figure out how to do it with just one value (either playstation or xbox). But i can't for the life of me figure out how to do it from multiple values in the dropdown. I want it to do the same for 2 of the values in the dropdown.

This is the code i have so far:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  jQuery("select#field_190").change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == ["Playstation", "Xbox"]) {
      jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").hide();
    } else {
  jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").show();
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

My HTML for the dropdown:

```
<div class="editfield field_190 field_platform required-field visibility-
public alt field_type_selectbox">


  <label for="field_190">
    Platform <span class="bp-required-field-label">(required)</span> 
</label>


  <select id="field_190" name="field_190" aria-required="true">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    <option value="Playstation">Playstation</option>
    <option value="Xbox">Xbox</option>
  </select>

  <p class="field-visibility-settings-notoggle" id="field-visibility-settings-toggle-190">
    This field can be seen by: <span class="current-visibility-level">Everyone</span> </p>


  <p class="description">Choose a which platform you use to play on.</p>

</div>
```

HTML for the checkboxes to show/hide

```
<div id="field_11" class="input-options checkbox-options">
  <label for="field_379_0" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_379_0" value="Counter 
Strike : Global Offensive">Counter Strike : Global Offensive</label>
  <label for="field_380_1" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_380_1" value="Diablo 
3">Diablo 3</label>
  <label for="field_381_2" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_381_2" value="League 
of Legends">League of Legends</label>
  <label for="field_382_3" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_382_3" value="World 
of Warcraft">World of Warcraft</label>
  <label for="field_383_4" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_383_4" 
value="Overwatch">Overwatch</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include your HTML as well, providing a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that will help us answer your question. If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  jQuery("select#field_190").change(function() {
    var arr_val = ["Playstation", "Xbox"];
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr_val) !== -1) {
       jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").hide();
    } else {
       jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").show();
    }
  });

});
```

See it in action

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  jQuery("select#field_190").change(function() {
    var arr_val = ["Playstation", "Xbox"];
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr_val) !== -1) {
       jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").hide();
    } else {
       jQuery("label[for='field_339_0'], label[for='field_341_2'], label[for='field_342_3']").show();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field_190" name="field_190" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">----</option>
  <option value="PC">PC</option>
  <option value="Playstation">Playstation</option>
  <option value="Xbox">Xbox</option>
</select>

<div id="field_11" class="input-options checkbox-options">
  <label for="field_339_0" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_339_0" value="Counter 
Strike : Global Offensive">Counter Strike : Global Offensive</label>
  <label for="field_340_1" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_340_1" value="Diablo 
3">Diablo 3</label>
  <label for="field_341_2" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_341_2" value="League 
of Legends">League of Legends</label>
  <label for="field_342_3" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_342_3" value="World 
of Warcraft">World of Warcraft</label>
  <label for="field_343_4" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_343_4" 
value="Overwatch">Overwatch</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. It still does not do anything.

Comment: @NicolaiKnudsen try `!== -1`

Comment: When i apply this code, it gives me the alert. But it does not hide the checkboxes. Do you know why?

Comment: @NicolaiKnudsen on your code there is no `label[for='field_339_0']` and no elements to hide or show .. if you change the code it will work .. answer updated

Comment: That selector with all of the `label[for='xyz']` is pretty horrible. It would be neater to say `jQuery("#field_379_0,#field_381_2,#field_382_3").parent().hide();` (noting that in the OP's code the `for` attributes don't match the related input IDs). But it would be neater still, and *much* easier to maintain to assign common classes to the elements and use those instead.

Comment: @nnnnnn you're totally right .. I updated my answer with input Ids .. but let me say sometimes while you didn't get a quick response from the OP . you feel something bad to continue updating your answer while you don't know this code works with him? not work? may be filter with `data` attribute instead of his selectors .. Sure you know there are more and more of codes to filter .. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code the elemets that you provided to hide/show does not exists in your Html. That is why You are doing it wrong.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  jQuery("select#field_190").change(function() {
    var arr_val = ["Playstation", "Xbox"];
    var labelFor = ["field_379_0","field_341_2","field_342_3"];
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr_val) !== -1) {
       jQuery("label[for='field_379_0'],label[for='field_381_2'],label[for='field_382_3']").hide();
    } else {
       jQuery("label[for='field_379_0'],label[for='field_381_2'],label[for='field_382_3']").show();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editfield field_190 field_platform required-field visibility-
public alt field_type_selectbox">


  <label for="field_190">
    Platform <span class="bp-required-field-label">(required)</span> 
</label>


  <select id="field_190" name="field_190" aria-required="true">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    <option value="Playstation">Playstation</option>
    <option value="Xbox">Xbox</option>
  </select>

  <p class="field-visibility-settings-notoggle" id="field-visibility-settings-toggle-190">
    This field can be seen by: <span class="current-visibility-level">Everyone</span> </p>


  <p class="description">Choose a which platform you use to play on.</p>

</div>

<div id="field_11" class="input-options checkbox-options">
  <label for="field_379_0" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_379_0" value="Counter 
Strike : Global Offensive">Counter Strike : Global Offensive</label>
  <label for="field_380_1" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_380_1" value="Diablo 
3">Diablo 3</label>
  <label for="field_381_2" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_381_2" value="League 
of Legends">League of Legends</label>
  <label for="field_382_3" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_382_3" value="World 
of Warcraft">World of Warcraft</label>
  <label for="field_383_4" class="option-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_11[]" id="field_383_4" 
value="Overwatch">Overwatch</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you copy/paste my snippet to your answer without making any different technique  .. So is there any logical reason for doing that??

Comment: *"...the elements...does not exists in your Html. That is why You are doing it wrong."* - The `if` condition was a pretty significant problem too, arguably something that needed to be fixed first in order to even notice the other problem, yet no mention of that in your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As some of you have said, i had the wrong ID's for my labels and that is why i wouldn't work. I've been working on this website for the last 8 hours, so i must have overlooked it :-)

Just if anyone needs it for the next time, this is the solution i came up with:

```
jQuery(function($) {

jQuery("select#field_190").change(function() {
    var arr_val = ["Playstation", "Xbox"];
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr_val) !== -1) {
        jQuery("#field_379_0, #field_381_2, #field_382_3").prop({disabled: true});
    } else {
        jQuery("#field_379_0, #field_381_2, #field_382_3").prop({disabled: false});
    }
  });

});
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Given that the key part was using the `$.inArray()` method, and that the element IDs were more of a typo, *and* that you seem to have now changed the requirement to disable the checkboxes rather than hiding them and their labels, wouldn't it have been better to just accept @Mohamed-Yousef's answer? (This answer does not answer the question because it doesn't hide/show anything.)

Comment: P.S. The if/else structure can be replaced with a one-liner: `jQuery("#field_379_0, #field_381_2, #field_382_3").prop({disabled: jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr_val) !== -1)});`

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes i just accepted his answer as the right one!
- Im very new to Stackoverflow, so i was not quite sure how things works here. Sorry about that!

And i am usually a designer, so coding is new for me. I will try your suggestion. Thank you very much.